# Getting the next bill date using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query that will select a list of recurring orders that were created every (30,60,90,Nx30) days ago. I don't want to use cursors if it is not necessary. The goal is to be able to run a query that shows me orders that will bill today.

I realize this code will not work, but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
declare @period int;
set @period = 30;

select @period = @period - @period, [id] from orders 
where 
    datepart(year, StartedAt) =  datepart(year, (dateadd(day, -@period, getutcdate())))
    and datepart(month, StartedAt) =  datepart(month, (dateadd(day, -@period, getutcdate())))
    and datepart(day, StartedAt) =  datepart(day, (dateadd(day, -@period, getutcdate())))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get rows from `orders` where the number of days since `StartedAt` is a multiple of the period.  If so, this should do what you want:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where datediff(day, StartedAt, getutcdate()) % @period = 0;
```

This calculates the number of dates between today and `StartedAt` and then uses the "mod" operator to determine if it is a multiple of `@period`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Worked like a charm! Thank you!